# How to add TextField to ListView in NativeScript?

Tags: listview, angular, nativescript

I have problem with TextField in ListView. Everytime when I tap to TextField, keyboard is show and automatically hide. I don't really know why is keyboard hiding..

So I have normal project (on ways nativecsript.org - Sample Grocery app). I'm testing it on Android 6 - device LG Nexus 5 (not emulator).

In list service are data fetched from API and then in list component is created array - itemsList from fetched data. Here is View code (list.html):

```
<ListView [items]="itemsList" class="small-spacing" orientation="vertical" rowHeight="auto">
    <template let-item="item">
            <TextField hint="{{item.name}}" ></TextField>
    </template>
  </ListView>
```

Thank you very much for any answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I did it. I had to change my code from ListView to angular *ngFor method, like this:

```
<StackLayout *ngFor="let item of itemsList">
   <TextField [hint]="item.name" [(ngModel)]="myTextfieldData"></TextField>
</StackLayout>
```

I hope that it helps someone. If you want to create scroll view, wrap this code to < ScrollView > element.

Comment: Btw, this was a bug in NS and in new version it's fixed ;) https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/2942

Answer (score 0):

This is NativeScript Core binding:

```
<TextField hint="{{item.name}}" ></TextField>
```

What you need is Angular-2 binding syntax (like when you are initializing [items])

```
<TextField [hint]="item.name" ></TextField>
```

And if you need two-way binding with the input value then you can use ngModel for the text property

```
<TextField [hint]="item.name" [(ngModel)]="myTextfieldData"></TextField>
```

As for the hiding/showing the keyboard issue in Android you can refer to the sample code used in the Groceries app. The methods is using native techniques to control the keyboard apperiance.

```
  handleAndroidFocus(textField, container) {
    if (container.android) {
      container.android.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
      container.android.setFocusable(true);
      textField.android.clearFocus();
    }
  }
```

The whole example can be found [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-Groceries/blob/2e36c8cb32a5a8578a484c37cc80e248560a920d/app/groceries/groceries.component.ts#L51-L57)

Comment: Once more, thank you for your answer. I tested it but it's not working. At the moment I have 6 items in array - 6 times is called function handleAndroidFocus (I typed here console.log - it;s working). But everytime when I tap on TextField is show and hide keyboard.. It didn't solve my problem with automatically hidden keyboard.

Comment: I reproduced the issue and logged it here: https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/2942 Stay in touch for fixes and possible solutions (currently it appears to work in Landscape mode only)

Comment: Btw, here is video how it works (show and hide keyboard): https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzYl86x0Xy6LSjY4ODlja1pqdlU